# C programming - sscanf to read similar lines

Tags: c, fgets, scanf

I am currently writing a program that intends to read from a url and prints out information about the weather. Omitting the lines of code that actually make a connection with the url, here is the loop that cycles through the information displayed on the given url, along with pertinent variables:

```
FILE *f = fdopen(sockfd, "r+");

char line[1000];
int count = 0;
int i;
char otime[200];
float temp;
int hum;
char dir[10];
float speed;
int fcastTempHi;
int fcastTempLo;
char wkday1[40];
char wkday2[20];
char wkday3[20];
char wkday4[20];

while(fgets(line, 1000, f) != NULL)
{
    sscanf(line, "\t\t\"observation_time\":\"%[^\"]\",", otime);
    sscanf(line, "\t\t\"temp_f\":%f\",", &temp);
    sscanf(line, "\t\t\"relative_humidity\":\"%d\",", &hum);
    sscanf(line, "\t\t\"wind_dir\":\"%[^\"]\",", dir);
    sscanf(line, "\t\t\"wind_mph\":%f\",", &speed);

    sscanf(line, "\t\t\"period\":1,");

}  
printf("Current Conditions\n");
printf("Observation time: %s\n", otime);
printf("Temperature: %f F\n", temp);
printf("Humidity: %d%%\n", hum);
printf("Wind: %s %f mph\n\n", dir, speed);
printf("Forecast\n");
//printf("%s:\n", wkday1);

fclose(f);
```

assume all values I have scanned for are present within the displayed url content, but I will only include the content I am now interested in;
reading from

```
    "period":1,
    "high": {
    "fahrenheit":"69",
    "celsius":"20"
    },
    "low": {
    "fahrenheit":"49",
    "celsius":"9"
    },
"weekday_short":"Sat",
"weekday":"Saturday",
```

I am trying to locate the line "period":1, and if it is found, I want to go on to locate "weekday":"string", and print the string later on. Unfortunately, there is another line from which I am scanning that looks like

```
    "period":1,
    "icon":"nt_partlycloudy",
```

and these lines occur much sooner than the period 1 that I am looking for. 
The reason I am looking for "period":1 in particular and not simply just scanning for "weekday" is because weekday is displayed multiple times as this is a weather forecast of 10 days. So I want the particular period that contains the weekday I need (period:1) and not the other periods (period:2,3,4,5,6 ... etc) as these contain the weekdays to follow.

I have attempted to use if statements, however this was only able to find the two occurrences of "period:1" and I was not able to scan anything afterwards.

I tried fork once the first instance of "period":1, was found, however this did not work (most likely from my lack of experience and general ignorance with fork).

To keep the post short, I'll exclude the other methods I tried, but I will say that I have gotten the program to at least recognize there are two lines that read "period":1, though I am just not sure how to approach this such that I can scan for the lines following the second instance of "period":1,. 
Thanks in advance for any replies.

More from the source:

```
{
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"REDACTED",
  "features": {
  "conditions": 1
  ,
  "forecast10day": 1
  }
    }
  , "current_observation": {
        "image": {
        "url":"REDACTED",
        "title":"REDACTED",
        "link":"REDACTED"
        },
        "display_location": {
        "full":"REDACTED",
        "city":"REDACTED",
        "state":"REDACTED",
        "state_name":"REDACTED",
        "country":"US",
        "country_iso3166":"US",
        "zip":"REDACTED",
        "magic":"1",
        "wmo":"99999",
        "latitude":"REDACTED",
        "longitude":"REDACTED",
        "elevation":"REDACTED"
        },
        "observation_location": {
        "full":"REDACTED",
        "city":"REDACTED",
        "state":"REDACTED",
        "country":"US",
        "country_iso3166":"US",
        "latitude":"REDACTED",
        "longitude":"REDACTED",
        "elevation":"705 ft"
        },
        "estimated": {
        },
        "station_id":"REDACTED",
        "observation_time":"Last Updated on May 15, 4:17 PM PDT",
        "observation_time_rfc822":"Fri, 15 May 2015 16:17:57 -0700",
        "observation_epoch":"1431731877",
        "local_time_rfc822":"Fri, 15 May 2015 16:18:17 -0700",
        "local_epoch":"1431731897",
        "local_tz_short":"PDT",
        "local_tz_long":"REDACTED",
        "local_tz_offset":"-0700",
        "weather":"Partly Cloudy",
        "temperature_string":"68.3 F (20.2 C)",
        "temp_f":68.3,
        "temp_c":20.2,
        "relative_humidity":"53%",
        "wind_string":"From the South at 3.2 MPH Gusting to 6.5 MPH",
        "wind_dir":"South",
        "wind_degrees":185,
        "wind_mph":3.2,
        "wind_gust_mph":"6.5",
        "wind_kph":5.1,
        "wind_gust_kph":"10.5",
        "pressure_mb":"1011",
        "pressure_in":"29.87",
        "pressure_trend":"-",
        "dewpoint_string":"51 F (11 C)",
        "dewpoint_f":51,
        "dewpoint_c":11,
        "heat_index_string":"NA",
        "heat_index_f":"NA",
        "heat_index_c":"NA",
        "windchill_string":"NA",
        "windchill_f":"NA",
        "windchill_c":"NA",
        "feelslike_string":"68.3 F (20.2 C)",
        "feelslike_f":"68.3",
        "feelslike_c":"20.2",
        "visibility_mi":"10.0",
        "visibility_km":"16.1",
        "solarradiation":"--",
        "UV":"7","precip_1hr_string":"0.00 in ( 0 mm)",
        "precip_1hr_in":"0.00",
        "precip_1hr_metric":" 0",
        "precip_today_string":"-999.00 in (-25375 mm)",
        "precip_today_in":"-999.00",
        "precip_today_metric":"--",
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "forecast_url":"REDACTED",
        "history_url":"REDACTED",
        "ob_url":"REDACTED",
        "nowcast":""
    }
        ,
    "forecast":{
        "txt_forecast": {
        "date":"2:52 PM PDT",
        "forecastday": [
        {
        "period":0,
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "title":"Friday",
        "fcttext":"Partly cloudy. Lows overnight in the upper 40s.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Partly cloudy. Low 9C.",
        "pop":"0"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":1,
        "icon":"nt_partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "title":"Friday Night",
        "fcttext":"Some passing clouds. Low 49F. Winds SSE at 5 to 10 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Partly cloudy. Low 9C. Winds SSE at 10 to 15 km/h.",
        "pop":"0"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":2,
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "title":"Saturday",
        "fcttext":"Sunshine and clouds mixed. High 76F. Winds SSW at 5 to 10 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Sunshine and clouds mixed. High 24C. Winds SSW at 10 to 15 km/h.",
        "pop":"0"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":3,
        "icon":"nt_partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "title":"Saturday Night",
        "fcttext":"A few clouds from time to time. Low 49F. Winds S at 5 to 10 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Partly cloudy skies. Low 9C. Winds S at 10 to 15 km/h.",
        "pop":"10"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":4,
        "icon":"mostlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "title":"Sunday",
        "fcttext":"More clouds than sun. High 74F. Winds SSW at 5 to 10 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Mainly cloudy. High 23C. Winds SSW at 10 to 15 km/h.",
        "pop":"10"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":5,
        "icon":"nt_partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "title":"Sunday Night",
        "fcttext":"Mostly cloudy skies early will become partly cloudy late. Low around 50F. Winds S at 5 to 10 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Mostly cloudy skies early, then partly cloudy after midnight. Low near 10C. Winds S at 10 to 15 km/h.",
        "pop":"10"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":6,
        "icon":"clear",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "title":"Monday",
        "fcttext":"A few passing clouds, otherwise generally sunny. High 74F. Winds SSW at 10 to 15 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"A few clouds early, otherwise mostly sunny. High 24C. Winds SSW at 15 to 25 km/h.",
        "pop":"10"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":7,
        "icon":"nt_partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "title":"Monday Night",
        "fcttext":"Partly cloudy skies. Low around 50F. Winds S at 10 to 15 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"A few clouds from time to time. Low near 10C. Winds S at 15 to 25 km/h.",
        "pop":"10"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":8,
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "title":"Tuesday",
        "fcttext":"Partly cloudy skies. High 74F. Winds S at 10 to 15 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Some clouds in the morning will give way to mainly sunny skies for the afternoon. High 24C. Winds S at 15 to 25 km/h.",
        "pop":"10"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":9,
        "icon":"nt_clear",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "title":"Tuesday Night",
        "fcttext":"Clear. Low near 50F. Winds S at 10 to 15 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"A mostly clear sky. Low near 10C. Winds S at 15 to 25 km/h.",
        "pop":"10"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":10,
        "icon":"clear",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "title":"Wednesday",
        "fcttext":"Sun and a few passing clouds. High 77F. Winds SSW at 5 to 10 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Sunshine along with some cloudy intervals. High near 25C. Winds SSW at 10 to 15 km/h.",
        "pop":"10"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":11,
        "icon":"nt_clear",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "title":"Wednesday Night",
        "fcttext":"Mainly clear skies. Low 51F. Winds S at 5 to 10 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Mainly clear skies. Low 11C. Winds S at 10 to 15 km/h.",
        "pop":"20"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":12,
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "title":"Thursday",
        "fcttext":"Sunshine and clouds mixed. High 77F. Winds SSW at 5 to 10 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Intervals of clouds and sunshine. High near 25C. Winds SSW at 10 to 15 km/h.",
        "pop":"10"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":13,
        "icon":"nt_chancetstorms",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "title":"Thursday Night",
        "fcttext":"Isolated thunderstorms during the evening, then partly cloudy overnight. Low 53F. Winds S at 5 to 10 mph. Chance of rain 30%.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Widely scattered showers or a thunderstorm early. Then partly cloudy. Low 12C. Winds S at 10 to 15 km/h. Chance of rain 30%.",
        "pop":"30"
        }
        {
        "period":14,
        "icon":"clear",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "title":"Friday",
        "fcttext":"Mostly sunny skies. High 78F. Winds SSW at 5 to 10 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Sunshine. High around 25C. Winds SSW at 10 to 15                km/h.",
    "pop":"10"
    }
    ,
    {
    "period":15,
    "icon":"nt_clear",
    "icon_url":"REDACTED",
    "title":"Friday Night",
    "fcttext":"A mostly clear sky. Low 54F. Winds S at 5 to 10 mph.",
    "fcttext_metric":"Clear skies. Low 12C. Winds S at 10 to 15 km/h.",
    "pop":"10"
    }
    ,
    {
    "period":16,
    "icon":"clear",
    "icon_url":"REDACTED",
    "title":"Saturday",
    "fcttext":"Mainly sunny. High 81F. Winds SSW at 5 to 10 mph.",
    "fcttext_metric":"Sunny skies. High 27C. Winds SSW at 10 to 15 km/h.",
    "pop":"10"
    }
    ,
    {
    "period":17,
    "icon":"nt_clear",
    "icon_url":"REDACTED",
    "title":"Saturday Night",
    "fcttext":"A few clouds from time to time. Low 53F. Winds S at 5 to 10 mph.",
    "fcttext_metric":"Mostly clear skies. Low 12C. Winds S at 10 to 15 km/h.",
    "pop":"10"
    }
    ,
    {
    "period":18,
    "icon":"clear",
    "icon_url":"REDACTED",
    "title":"Sunday",
    "fcttext":"Mostly sunny skies. High 82F. Winds SSW at 5 to 10 mph.",
    "fcttext_metric":"A few clouds from time to time. High 28C. Winds SSW at 10 to 15 km/h.",
    "pop":"10"
    }
    ,
    {
    "period":19,
    "icon":"nt_clear",
    "icon_url":"REDACTED",
    "title":"Sunday Night",
    "fcttext":"Mostly clear. Low 53F. Winds SSE at 5 to 10 mph.",
    "fcttext_metric":"A mostly clear sky. Low 12C. Winds SSE at 10 to 15 km/h.",
    "pop":"10"
    }
        ]
        },
        "simpleforecast": {
        "forecastday": [
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1431741600",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM PDT on May 15, 2015",
    "day":15,
    "month":5,
    "year":2015,
    "yday":134,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"1",
    "monthname":"May",
    "monthname_short":"May",
    "weekday_short":"Fri",
    "weekday":"Friday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"PDT",
    "tz_long":"REDACTED"
},
        "period":1,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"69",
        "celsius":"20"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"49",
        "celsius":"9"
        },
        "conditions":"Partly Cloudy",
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":0,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": null,
        "mm": null
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": null,
        "cm": null
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 8,
        "kph": 13,
        "dir": "",
        "degrees": 0
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 1,
        "kph": 2,
        "dir": "South",
        "degrees": 186
        },
        "avehumidity": 73,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ,
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1431828000",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM PDT on May 16, 2015",
    "day":16,
    "month":5,
    "year":2015,
    "yday":135,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"1",
    "monthname":"May",
    "monthname_short":"May",
    "weekday_short":"Sat",
    "weekday":"Saturday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"PDT",
    "tz_long":"REDACTED"
},
        "period":2,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"76",
        "celsius":"24"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"49",
        "celsius":"9"
        },
        "conditions":"Partly Cloudy",
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":0,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 10,
        "kph": 16,
        "dir": "SSW",
        "degrees": 196
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 8,
        "kph": 13,
        "dir": "SSW",
        "degrees": 196
        },
        "avehumidity": 54,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ,
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1431914400",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM PDT on May 17, 2015",
    "day":17,
    "month":5,
    "year":2015,
    "yday":136,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"1",
    "monthname":"May",
    "monthname_short":"May",
    "weekday_short":"Sun",
    "weekday":"Sunday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"PDT",
    "tz_long":"REDACTED"
},
        "period":3,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"74",
        "celsius":"23"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"50",
        "celsius":"10"
        },
        "conditions":"Mostly Cloudy",
        "icon":"mostlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":10,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 10,
        "kph": 16,
        "dir": "SSW",
        "degrees": 192
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 9,
        "kph": 14,
        "dir": "SSW",
        "degrees": 192
        },
        "avehumidity": 54,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ,
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1432000800",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM PDT on May 18, 2015",
    "day":18,
    "month":5,
    "year":2015,
    "yday":137,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"1",
    "monthname":"May",
    "monthname_short":"May",
    "weekday_short":"Mon",
    "weekday":"Monday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"PDT",
    "tz_long":"REDACTE"
},
        "period":4,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"74",
        "celsius":"23"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"50",
        "celsius":"10"
        },
        "conditions":"Clear",
        "icon":"clear",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":10,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 15,
        "kph": 24,
        "dir": "SSW",
        "degrees": 209
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 10,
        "kph": 16,
        "dir": "SSW",
        "degrees": 209
        },
        "avehumidity": 52,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ,
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1432087200",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM PDT on May 19, 2015",
    "day":19,
    "month":5,
    "year":2015,
    "yday":138,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"1",
    "monthname":"May",
    "monthname_short":"May",
    "weekday_short":"Tue",
    "weekday":"Tuesday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"PDT",
    "tz_long":"REDACTED"
},
        "period":5,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"74",
        "celsius":"23"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"50",
        "celsius":"10"
        },
        "conditions":"Partly Cloudy",
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":10,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 15,
        "kph": 24,
        "dir": "S",
        "degrees": 190
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 10,
        "kph": 16,
        "dir": "S",
        "degrees": 190
        },
        "avehumidity": 55,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ,
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1432173600",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM PDT on May 20, 2015",
    "day":20,
    "month":5,
    "year":2015,
    "yday":139,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"1",
    "monthname":"May",
    "monthname_short":"May",
    "weekday_short":"Wed",
    "weekday":"Wednesday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"PDT",
    "tz_long":"REDACTED"
},
        "period":6,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"77",
        "celsius":"25"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"51",
        "celsius":"11"
        },
        "conditions":"Clear",
        "icon":"clear",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":10,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 10,
        "kph": 16,
        "dir": "SSW",
        "degrees": 196
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 9,
        "kph": 14,
        "dir": "SSW",
        "degrees": 196
        },
        "avehumidity": 54,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ,
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1432260000",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM PDT on May 21, 2015",
    "day":21,
    "month":5,
    "year":2015,
    "yday":140,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"1",
    "monthname":"May",
    "monthname_short":"May",
    "weekday_short":"Thu",
    "weekday":"Thursday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"PDT",
    "tz_long":"REDACTED"
},
        "period":7,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"77",
        "celsius":"25"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"53",
        "celsius":"12"
        },
        "conditions":"Partly Cloudy",
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":10,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 10,
        "kph": 16,
        "dir": "SSW",
        "degrees": 195
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 8,
        "kph": 13,
        "dir": "SSW",
        "degrees": 195
        },
        "avehumidity": 53,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ,
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1432346400",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM PDT on May 22, 2015",
    "day":22,
    "month":5,
    "year":2015,
    "yday":141,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"1",
    "monthname":"May",
    "monthname_short":"May",
    "weekday_short":"Fri",
    "weekday":"Friday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"PDT",
    "tz_long":"REDACTED"
},
        "period":8,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"78",
        "celsius":"26"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"54",
        "celsius":"12"
        },
        "conditions":"Clear",
        "icon":"clear",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":10,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 10,
        "kph": 16,
        "dir": "SSW",
        "degrees": 208
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 8,
        "kph": 13,
        "dir": "SSW",
        "degrees": 208
        },
        "avehumidity": 59,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ,
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1432432800",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM PDT on May 23, 2015",
    "day":23,
    "month":5,
    "year":2015,
    "yday":142,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"1",
    "monthname":"May",
    "monthname_short":"May",
    "weekday_short":"Sat",
    "weekday":"Saturday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"PDT",
    "tz_long":"REDACTED"
},
        "period":9,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"81",
        "celsius":"27"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"53",
        "celsius":"12"
        },
        "conditions":"Clear",
        "icon":"clear",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":10,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 10,
        "kph": 16,
        "dir": "SSW",
        "degrees": 202
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 9,
        "kph": 14,
        "dir": "SSW",
        "degrees": 202
        },
        "avehumidity": 57,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ,
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1432519200",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM PDT on May 24, 2015",
    "day":24,
    "month":5,
    "year":2015,
    "yday":143,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"1",
    "monthname":"May",
    "monthname_short":"May",
    "weekday_short":"Sun",
    "weekday":"Sunday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"PDT",
    "tz_long":"REDACTED"
},
        "period":10,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"82",
        "celsius":"28"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"53",
        "celsius":"12"
        },
        "conditions":"Clear",
        "icon":"clear",
        "icon_url":"REDACTED",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":10,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 10,
        "kph": 16,
        "dir": "SSW",
        "degrees": 206
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 9,
        "kph": 14,
        "dir": "SSW",
        "degrees": 206
        },
        "avehumidity": 55,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ]
        }
    }
}
```

I've updated with all data from the source.

Comment: It would be easier to do `char *rightSide = strchr(line, ':')`, and parse the value at `rightSide + 1`.

Comment: I see what you are saying, however there are still two (or more) instances in which 1 would occur at the rightSide of :

Comment: Can you please post more of the input file?

Comment: Updated with more input.

Comment: I really don't know a lot about the format, and have barely used it, but I believe it's JSON, JavaScript Object Notation, there are many parsers that you can download online as libraries, and use them in your program. It will not be simple to parse it with standard library functions, the data has a structure, and if you use the right tool you will be able to use that structure.

Comment: Yes it is JSON, however the goal was specifically not to use a library.

Comment: Why not?, is it an embedded platform or something similar where using a library would be painful or not possible at all. Also, from the issues you are facing, it looks like you have no option but a library or writing a parser yourself, because you need to know the data structure to extract the parts you are interested in.

Comment: It is an assignment that is designed to fetch a url and interact with any contents. In this case, the weather output. Although in a real world scenario one would use a library to parse through this, it was noted that the class was to do this without that.

Comment: Well, maybe you need to write functions that will handle most of what a JSON library would do.  Note in particular that JSON is apt to include very few newlines in the data; it often arrives as a single line of input.  Be careful how you go about handling it.

Comment: I am very surprized that the sscanf() calls work, as they all are starting at the beginning of the 'line[]' array.   Suggest using strstr() to find the occurrance of the desired label. (as long as working with only first period, that should be fairly straight forward).   use the returned pointer to step forward to the data,  Then extract/convert the data.  then repeat the above statements to find/extract/convert the next data.   Suggest using a table of each of the labels, in the order found in the incomming data to minimize the amoung of code that must be written.

Comment: since sscanf() stops on any white space and '\t' (tab) is white space, I would expect each of the posted sscanf() statements to fail  You could skip over all the 'icon' problem by first using strstr() to find 'simpleforecast' then moving forward from there.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand, you are trying to check if there are two instances of `"period": 1` and if there are, read another value. In that case, I believe something like this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
  // I stored the data in weather.txt, you'll have to change this
  FILE *f = fopen("weather.txt", "r+");

  char line[1000];
  int count = 0;
  int i;
  char otime[200];
  float temp;
  int hum;
  char dir[10];
  float speed;
  int fcastTempHi;
  int fcastTempLo;
  char wkday1[40];
  char wkday2[20];
  char wkday3[20];
  char wkday4[20];

  int period1 = 0;       // Keep track of how many period: 1's we've seen
  int value = 0;         // Temp variable to store value
  bool haswkday = false; // Bool for if we've gotten the value or not

  while(fgets(line, 1000, f) != NULL)
  {
      sscanf(line, "\t\t\"observation_time\":\"%[^\"]\",", otime);
      sscanf(line, "\t\t\"temp_f\":%f\",", &temp);
      sscanf(line, "\t\t\"relative_humidity\":\"%d\",", &hum);
      sscanf(line, "\t\t\"wind_dir\":\"%[^\"]\",", dir);
      sscanf(line, "\t\t\"wind_mph\":%f\",", &speed);

      // If period is scanned successfully and its value is 1
      if (sscanf(line, "\t\t\"period\":%d,", &value) != 0 && value == 1)
      {
        period1++; // Increase how many times we've seen it
      }

      // If we've seen exactly 2 period: 1's, then also check for weekday
      if (period1 == 2 && sscanf(line, "\t\t\"weekday\":\"%[^\"]\"", &wkday1) > 0)
      {
        haswkday = true; // Weekday value already stored, say that we've gotten it
      }
  }  
  printf("Current Conditions\n");
  printf("Observation time: %s\n", otime);
  printf("Temperature: %f F\n", temp);
  printf("Humidity: %d%%\n", hum);
  printf("Wind: %s %f mph\n\n", dir, speed);
  printf("Forecast\n");

  // If we got the value, then print it
  if (haswkday)
  {
    printf("%s:\n", wkday1);
  }

  fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: This is a clever approach to the problem. I was very familiar with booleans from java, however the topic was not even covered in my C class and I did not even think to use it. This method will print out a weekday just fine (whereas I was getting just random characters) however it seems to be a day ahead. The print value should read Saturday (given today's date), but it instead prints Sunday. I'm working with it though currently, but I thought I'd give you some feedback. If I find a way to get it to print the true day, I'll respond. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @JavaFuntimeEngine Are you getting Sunday with the exact code I posted? Perhaps you can post the data that is giving the wrong output and I can take a look at it. The data I have doesn't have any instances of "weekday":"Sunday" in it.

Comment: The data contains two sections of "periods" from 0 to 19, and from 1 to 10. I cut off the data at "period":2, (in the interest of not making this page incredibly full with text) which would have had the information "weekday": "Sunday", attached to it. Similarly, there would be a period 3, with its amplifying data and a "weekday": "Monday", and so on until period 10 is reached. I'll edit the current text to reflect this.

Comment: @JavaFuntimeEngine you really need to write a parser, there is no better option, I will delete my answer, just write the parser, JSON doesn't seem to be so hard, it's not like writing a xml parser which is really really difficult.

Comment: It seems likely that this is actually instead scanning the last instance of "weekday":"string", and storing that value.

Comment: If that's the case, then simply add a check for `haswkday` before you assign the value.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, thanks to ozdrgnaDiies, I've found this solution. All that was added to his solution was simply incrementing period1 once the instance of wkday1 was found so that it would no longer increment until all periods were covered.

```
FILE *f = fdopen(sockfd, "r+");

char line[1000];
char otime[200];
float temp;
int hum;
char dir[10];
float speed;
int fcastTempHi;
int fcastTempLo;
char wkday1[40];
char wkday2[20];
char wkday3[20];
char wkday4[20];

int period1 = 0;       // Keep track of how many period: 1's we've seen
int value = 0;         // Temp variable to store value
bool haswkday = false; // Bool for if we've gotten the value or not
while(fgets(line, 1000, f) != NULL)// fgets returns NULL, whereas fscanf returns EOF
{
    sscanf(line, "\t\t\"observation_time\":\"%[^\"]\",", otime);
    sscanf(line, "\t\t\"temp_f\":%f\",", &temp);
    sscanf(line, "\t\t\"relative_humidity\":\"%d\",", &hum);
    sscanf(line, "\t\t\"wind_dir\":\"%[^\"]\",", dir);
    sscanf(line, "\t\t\"wind_mph\":%f\",", &speed);

    // If period is scanned successfully and its value is 1
    if(sscanf(line, "\t\t\"period\":%d,", &value) != 0 && value == 1)
    {
        period1++; // Increase how many times we've seen it
    }

    // If we've seen exactly 2 period: 1's, then also check for weekday
    if(period1 == 2 && sscanf(line, "\t\"weekday\":\"%[^\"]\"", wkday1) > 0)
    {
        haswkday = true; // Weekday value already stored, say that we've gotten it

        period1++;
    }       
}  
printf("Current Conditions\n");
printf("Observation time: %s\n", otime);
printf("Temperature: %f F\n", temp);
printf("Humidity: %d%%\n", hum); 
printf("Wind: %s %f mph\n\n", dir, speed);
printf("Forecast\n");
// If we got the value, then print it
if(haswkday)
{
    printf("%s:\n", wkday1);
}

fclose(f);
```

This will successfully print out the day of the week following the current day.
Thanks again.